# Bigcup, bigwedge etc. inside brackets gets space above

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I want to have the following formula:

```
\[\Phi=\{\phi\}\cup\left\{\exists \mathsf{x_0}\ldots\exists \mathsf{x_{n-1}}\left[\bigwedge_{0\leq i<j\leq n-1} \mathsf{x_i}\neq\mathsf{x_j}\right]\right\}\]
```

which outputs to this:
[image]

As you can see, I get a huge space above my `\bidwedge`. The usage of `\limits` doesn't change anything. How can I get a more decent looking set?

Comment: Off-topic: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to?s=1|1.6965

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\left` and `\right` always produce fences which are symmetric with respect to the formula axis, that is, the imaginary line where fraction lines would lie on.

With big operators having limits there is no need the fences cover them; in this case `\bigg` is sufficient and avoids too large delimiters. There's only one small manual fix: adding `\,` between the bracket and the operator, because the limit is very wide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\Phi=\{\phi\}\cup
  \biggl\{\exists \mathsf{x_0}\dots
         \exists \mathsf{x_{n-1}}
  \biggl[\,\bigwedge_{0\leq i<j\leq n-1} \mathsf{x_i}\neq\mathsf{x_j}
  \biggr]
  \biggr\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, I would give a try to `\Big`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\Phi=\{\phi\}\cup
  \Bigl\{\exists \mathsf{x_0}\dots
         \exists \mathsf{x_{n-1}}
  \Bigl[\,\bigwedge_{0\leq i<j\leq n-1} \mathsf{x_i}\neq\mathsf{x_j}
  \Bigr]
  \Bigr\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should the characters -- 0. 1, i, and j -- that are used to index elements of the `x` sequence be typeset in sans-serif or in "regular" math italics? The OP's code uses both font styles, but that may not be optimal.

Comment: @Mico I don't really understand the OP's choice of fonts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the `\big,\Big,\bigg, \Bigg` commands to adjust the size of the delimiters to your needs. This can be automatised with the `DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`. An example is the `\set` command which be used in the `\set*` version, which corresponds to a pair of `\left … \right`; alternatively, it accepts an optional argument `\big`, `\Big`, &c.

I suggest one of these codes, without square brackets, that don't look too good in this context, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\set{\{}{\}}

\begin{document}

\[\Phi=\{\phi\}\cup\set[\bigg]{\exists \mathsf{x_0}\ldots\exists \mathsf{x_{n-1}}\left(\smash[b]{\bigwedge_{0\leq i<j\leq n-1}} \mathsf{x_i}\neq\mathsf{x_j}\right)}\]
\[\Phi=\{\phi\}\cup\biggl\{\exists \mathsf{x_0}\ldots\exists \mathsf{x_{n-1}}\textsf{, } \smash[b]{\bigwedge_{0\leq i<j\leq n-1}} \mathsf{x_i}\neq\mathsf{x_j}\biggr\}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to reserve the use of `\mathsf` for the names of variables; I wouldn't extend its use to the indexing variables `0`, `i`, `j`, `n-1`, etc. To write the expression more compactly, you may also want to load the `mathtools` package (a superset of the `amsmath` package) and that package's `\smashoperator` directive. Finally, as the other answers have suggested as well, I wouldn't use the `\left` and `\right` directives to size the parentheses since the size that's produced by this method is excessive, typographically speaking; use `\biggl` and `\biggr` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\smashoperator' macro
\begin{document}
\[
\Phi=\{\phi\} \cup
     \biggl\{\exists \mathsf{x}_0 \dots \exists \mathsf{x}_{n-1}
     \biggl[ \, \smashoperator[r]{\bigwedge_{0\leq i<j\leq n-1}} 
     \mathsf{x}_i \neq \mathsf{x}_j
  \biggr]
  \biggr\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I disagree about the use of mathsf, it indicates the variable names in the meta-language, and since the whole x_i is the name of the variable, I think it should all be in sans-serif. When a specific model is given and I'm talking in that models language, one would use x_i with serif in my opinion. Maybe it's useful to add this article is on model theory rather then general logic.

Comment: @konewka - If the indexing variables `i`, `j`, etc need to be in sans-serif, you should place the material below `\bigwedge` in mathsf-mode as well.

Comment: Ooh yeah, you're absolutely right, missed those, thanks!